# Confused about memset

Tags: c, sockets, networking, struct, memset

I am studying socket programming and i encountered this code.

```
struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
int status;
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage: showip hostname\n");
    return 1;
}

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); 
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    return 2;
}
```

I understand it all except one. Why this code memset'ed the struct hints but not the *res and *p?

Comment: better style would be to initialize `hints` instead of calling `memset`.

Answer (score 3):

The `res` pointer is to be populated by the [getaddrinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) function, and therefore does not need to be initialized by zero. `hints` on the other hand needs to be initialized, hence setting the whole structure to zero and then setting the only two fields that need to be set.

As you do not use `p` in your code - I cannot comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

The description of [getaddrinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) states that

> The getaddrinfo() function allocates and initializes a linked list of addrinfo structures, one for each network address that matches node and service, subject to any restrictions imposed by hints, and returns a pointer to the start of the list in res.

Which means you don't whant any other information in `hints` than strictly necessary (otherwise the function might produce undesired output).  Also, the "real" result of the function is returned in `res`, which means the current content of `res` is overwritten, so you don't really care what was in there before the function call (as long as you are not going to interpret it if the function fails).

Since the members of a struct (like `addrinfo`) are not initialized in any way when declaring a variable of that type, `hints` originally contains "garbage" -- whatever happed to be in memory where the variable is allocated.  Thus the code calls `memset` to zero out all members in an easy/fast way (as opposed to setting the member variables to zero one-by-one).

Answer (score 0):

It should not as you only memset hints to all 0s. Also res and p are pointer only not locating to any location at the time of memset call.

That is expected behavior. Let me know what is your exception and I will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Why this code memset'ed the struct hints but not the *res and *p?

Because, you are calling memset only once and passing only &hints as an argument to that memset.

```
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
```

If you want to memset *res & *p, first you need to allocate memory for the same as they are onlypointers and then you need to call memset seperately for each one of them by passing them as arguments.

Comment: So i can memset *res, however it doesnt make sense because the getaddrinfo will overwrite it anyway?

Comment: You cannot memset `*res`, because the pointer is invalid (contains "garbage" as it has not been initialized - thus pointing to invalid "object").  You could memset the pointer itself (`res`), but it is just as easy to assign zero to it (`res=0;`) if you wanted to do that.  And you are right, the function call will assign a new value to `res` when it returns.  -- Clarification: the type of `res` is `struct addrinfo *` (pointer to an addrinfo structure), the type of `*res` is `struct addrinfo` (the structure itself, not a pointer)